# Binary search tree recursion issue

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I have created a binary tree which arranges numbers. The numbers which are less than a node go to the left and the greater ones go to the right.

I have a tree object which has a root. I later set the first node as the root. node is another object constructed from a Node constructor having a value, left and right as arguments.

```
function Node(val){
    this.value = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}
```

I later set the left and right branches as nodes based on the value of `val`.

```
Node.prototype.branch= function(n){ //n is a New node            
    if(this.value > n.value){
        this.left = n;
    }else if (this.value < n.value){
        this.right = n;
    }

}
```

I was trying to traverse the tree using recursive function.
I visit each node and print the lowest value.

```
Node.prototype.visit = function(){
    if(this.left != null){
        this.left.visit();
    }
    console.log(this.value)
    if(this.right != null){
        this.right.visit();
    }

}
```

This above function works perfectly and prints all the numbers in an ascending order....but I dont understand how it goes to the smallest node, prints the value and goes back to the previous node...so if someone can give me an explanation it will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I have added one image for a clear explanation.

As far as I understood your question, you are stuck somewhere in between the recursion stack which is maintained every time you call the same function within itself. In that way each function gets stacked upon itself until it hits a return statement and eventually every function starts to pop and clear the call stack/recursion stack.

Let me try to explain what's happening in your case.

In your visit function, you keep on visiting the left nodes until you find the node which doesn't have left child. Till then you have added each left node which you visited into your call stack which will eventually return when your visit function returns.

Now when you are at the node which doesn't have the left child, you log its data which is the smallest node in the tree. 
I hope it is clear till now.

After that...

You again start to push into the call stack for any right child of the node which you logged out just now.

This again adds the right child to the call stack and then performs the visit function for it, which then logs out your second-most smallest node.

The problem which I see here is you are not using a return statement at the end of your visit function. Hence, the function will itself exit after it has hit the closing curly braces.

I hope I was able to clear things up a little bit. Thanks.

PS: In the image, please note when I logged "1" I mistakenly called it as step 4. Please call it 4.1 and you will not suffer in understanding the rest.
Also, this image just explains your problem only where you don't really visit the null child. You simply check if its child is null or not.

[image]

Comment: Yea my doubt has been cleared. Thank you. I was not aware that everytime I call a recursive function...the previous function gets added to the return stack. I was wondering how the function printed the values of the nodes   which occured before the smallest node

Comment: I am glad it helped. Thanks